# Creating a summary table of maximum values

Tags: r, max

I have a matrix of daily data of average flow and want to make a summary matrix that shows the maximum peak flow. Here's a little sample of what my data looks like:

```
x<-c(5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70,75,80,85,90,95,100)
flow<-matrix(c(c(rep(1990,365),rep(1991,365),rep(1992,365)),sample(x,(365*3), replace=TRUE)),nrow=(365*3), ncol=2)
```

I'd like the summary matrix to be formatted with the year in column 1 and the peak flow event from that year in column 2. Here's an example of how I would like the summary matrix formatted.

```
summary=matrix(, ncol=2, nrow=3)
summary[,1]=c(1990,1991,1992)
```

Comment: As an aside, don't use `<-` inside your `matrix()` call. This creates the variables `nrow` and `ncol` in your global environment. Use `=` instead, as they are not totally interchangeable in this context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be close:

```
DF <- as.data.frame(flow)
names(DF) <- c("year", "flow")
DF$year <- as.factor(DF$year)
res <- aggregate(flow ~ year, data = DF, FUN = max)
```

And gives:

```
  year flow
1 1990  100
2 1991  100
3 1992  100
```

in the form of a data frame.

Answer (score 1):

And the dplyr family of functions (building on @Bryans work):

```
DF <- as.data.frame(flow)
names(DF) <- c("year", "flow")
group_by(DF, year) %>% summarize(flow = max(flow))
```

Gives:

```
Source: local data frame [3 x 2]

  year flow
1 1990  100
2 1991  100
3 1992  100
```